# How to get the Distance, Collision and Direction for each game object in my list?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, distance, collision, game-physics

So, I've a list with a game objects and I'm very uncertan about how to get the distance, collistion, direction for each of them. It is sutable to use the SphereCast, to cover my needs, becouse I know it is only class functions that can do it for me. 
I wrote the code to accomplish the task, but its grabbing the data just for 1 game object in my list, insted of all of them, I wish to grab data from all game object in my list. Any ideas to change the code or approaches?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class example : MonoBehaviour {

    RaycastHit hit;

    Vector3 direction;

    public static  List<float> sphereCast = new List<float>();

    void Update() {
        CharacterController charCtrl = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
        foreach(GameObject g in xmlreaderUnityObject.unityGameObjectsToCDP)
        {
            Vector3 p1 = g.transform.position;
            if (Physics.SphereCast(p1, charCtrl.height / 2, g.transform.forward, out hit,1))    
            { 
                float distance = 0;
                float angleBetween = 0;
                float contact = 0; 
                if(hit.collider.enabled)
                {
                    direction = hit.transform.position - p1;
                    angleBetween = Vector3.Angle(g.transform.forward, direction);
                    contact = 1;
                    distance =  hit.distance;
                }
                print("Distance: "+ distance + " Collision: " + contact + " Direction: " + angleBetween + " hit point: "
                        +hit.point + " player position: " + p1);

                sphereCast.Add(contact);
                sphereCast.Add(distance);
                sphereCast.Add(angleBetween);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to set a bigger radius? Why do you use **goto**? As I can see the whole switch case construct is obvious. How many print outs do you get in your log view, 1 or more than 1 but always having the same values?

Comment: every gameobject which is active having their own values, a game objects which is inactive dont send nothing, but they should

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because it only hit one GameObject. I have set a Scene up where you it shows all the GameObjects it hit + which GameObject that send it. 
[Project Example](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/v7d9ksm5v1xcdqg/qFk44cmt_s/New%20Unity%20Project%206)

Comment: hey bro! the point is I need to get a digits from the objects that was hit. for example: cube hits sphere, we'll get digits(collision, direction, distance) from sphere. If not, will get null digits. And this need to be implemented for all object in the scene. So, if collided get digits, not get null, any ideas?

Comment: I have have updated the script so now it will retun 0 if not hit anything, else it return the data from the object it hit.